# How to pass extra data content on yii activeform's ajax parameters?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am trying to set up a ajax request when radio button is clicked. Here is my code that I am trying for.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'page', $pages, array('class' => 'span5', 'prompt' => '-- page --')); ?>    

<?php echo $form->radioButtonListInlineRow($model, 'for', array('desktop'=>'Desktop', 'mobile'=>'Mobile'), array('ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST', 
    'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/admin/adv/loadpositions'), //or $this->createUrl('loadcities') if '$this' extends CController
    'update'=>'#Adv_position', //or 'success' => 'function(data){...handle the data in the way you want...}',
    'data'=>array('for'=>'js:this.value', 'page' => 'XXXXXXXX'),
    ))); 
?>
```

I just want to pass its's value as well as it's upper field's value to the ajax action. How can I make it come true.  **'data'=>array('for'=>'js:this.value', 'page' => 'XXXXXXXX'),**.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> $(this.form).serialize()

Will give you the form data. Try something like:

```
<?php 
echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'for', array('desktop'=>'Desktop', 'mobile'=>'Mobile'), array('ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', 
'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/admin/adv/loadpositions'),     
'data'=>array('data'=>'js:$(this.form).serialize()'),
))); 
?>
```

**Update:**

You can easily parse this serialized string using PHP function `parse_str`

```
 <?php
 $data = 'str1=value1&str2=value2';
 parse_str($data);   
 echo $str1; //value1
 echo $str2; //value2
```

Comment: This sounds good.. But, while i print the POST data it displays `Array
(
    [data] => Adv%5Btitle%5D=&Adv%5Bpage%5D=profession&Adv%5Bfor%5D=&Adv%5Bfor%5D=desktop&Adv%5Bposition
%5D=0&Adv%5Bcode%5D=&Adv%5Bstatus%5D=1
)`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `data` attribute to something like this:

```
'data'=>array('for'=>'js:this.value', 'page' => 'js:$("#someId").val()'),
```